# node-pre-gyp info This Node instance does not support builds for N-API version 3

Tags: node.js

I am getting the above error in the server

when run node server using npm start it works fine but when I run using pm2 it throws the above error.

Comment: face the same problem. did you get any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Use node-v12.18.3 for solving this error

You can download this version by using this link

```
https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v12.18.3/
```

After installing the new version run as administrator

```
npm rebuild (windows)
sudo npm rebuild (Linux)
```

Also, check whether install windows build tool into the system